# missing 1 required positional argument

Tags: python, python-3.x, function

**mesaj_gonder code :**

```
def mesaj_gonder(self, kime, mesaj):
        mtype="chat"
        self.xmpp.send_message(mto=str(kime), mbody=str(mesaj), mtype=mtype)
```

**function call code:**

```
@zxlolbot.botcommand    
def mesaj(self, sender, args):
        kime = "sum503278@pvp.net/xiff"
        zxLoLBoT.mesaj_gonder(kime,str(args[0]))
```

**error ss:**

[image]

Ty for helps !

Comment: `zxLolBoT` is not an instance here but a class, so your method is left unbound. You are passing in `kime` as `self` and `str(args[0])` as `kime`. Show us how you are setting up `zxLolBoT` instead.

Comment: @MartijnPieters im edit topic

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to call an *unbound function*; `zxLolBoT` is a *class*, not an instance. As such, the `self` parameter is not being passed in for you, and the method only received 2 arguments instead of 3 (with `self` being that 3rd argument).

`self` is already that instance, access the method on that to get a bound version:

```
@zxlolbot.botcommand    
def mesaj(self, sender, args):
    kime = "sum503278@pvp.net/xiff"
    self.mesaj_gonder(kime, str(args[0]))
```